# Background image on a:hover overflow

Tags: css, overflow, background-image

Searched everywhere, tried several techniques, but haven't found a workable answer yet.

Goal: Display a 'pin' background image when hovering over the navigation item.
Issue:  Part of pin disappears when it extends past the a:hover tag because the background image is taller than the item

Current css is below.  All parent elements are set to overflow: visible

```
.menu-primary a  {
   display: block;
   padding: 6px 0 6px 0;
   text-align: center;
   width: 184px;
   height: auto;
   margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
   position: relative;;
   overflow: visible;
}

.menu-primary li#menu-item-23 a {
   background-color: #dfe6ab;
   margin-left: 0;
   overflow: visible;
}

.menu-primary li#menu-item-23 a:hover,
.menu-primary li#menu-item-23:hover a {
   background: url(images/pin.png) no-repeat left 0px top -7px;
   background-color: #dfe6ab;
   color: #000000;
   overflow: visible;
   height: auto;
 }
```

All suggestions welcome.  Thank you.

Comment: use z-indexing to laying the image on top without being cut off

Comment: Any chance you can add your code to a fiddle so we can take a look at it in action?

Comment: Seems like an ideal spot for a pseudo-element. JSfddle would be ideal...especially with the actual image.

Answer (score 0):

Background's in CSS don't act like Html Elements.  If you need the anchor to display it, but the anchor is too small.  You'll need to change the size of the anchor tag to the size of your image.  Otherwise you can change the background-size of the image inside to fit within the anchor.

Also, you've got a duplicate semi-colon(;) in .menu-primary a, see: 
    position: relative;;